# Application of Pigeonhole principle in geometry

Tags: geometry, pigeonhole-principle

Suppose there are $2n+3$ points such that no $3$ points are collinear and no $4$ points are concyclic. It is required to show that one can find at least one circle passing through $3$ points such that it has $n$ points inside it and $n$ points outside it. How to prove this?

I could do nothing significant in this problem. So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't know that the pigeonhole principle is the easiest way to work it out.

Comment: It seems difficult to identify the boxes in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Pick two points, $P$ and $Q$, such that all of the other $2n+1$ points are on the same side of the line $\overline{PQ}$. Let $\ell$ be the perpendicular bisector of the segment $PQ$, and let $R$ be the point of intersection of $\ell$ and that segment. Now imagine $R$ moving slowly away from the segment along $\ell$ on the side of $\overline{PQ}$ that does *not* contain the other $2n+1$ points. As soon as $R$ moves off $PQ$, the three points $P,Q$, and $R$ determine a circle. Initially that circle contains all $2n+1$ of the other points. (Why?) When $R$ has moved far enough, it contains none of them. (Why?) It never passes through more than one of them at a time. (Why?)

Comment: How did you know that the number of points in the circle can be decreased uniformly. It may be that at some time we find there are  n+3 points inside the circle .Then we need to exclude those 3 points . So we move R a bit farther. Now we may find that as R moves a bit away 5 points altogether gets excluded.(3 and 5 points are just random). How can we conclude that we will reach that configuration mentioned in the problem? (Maybe I misunderstood your hint but please clarify).

Comment: @Avi: What you’re describing can’t happen, because of the last assertion in my answer. (But apart from that you seem to have the right idea.)

Comment: Just a side question : Is the fact that no 4 points are con cyclic of no consequence.

Comment: @Avi: It’s crucial: it’s why the situation that you described in the other comment can’t happen. (I’ll be away from the computer for some hours now, but I will check back.)

Comment: @Avi `the fact that no 4 points are concyclic` answers the last `(Why?)` in the post.

Comment: Got it. But why did line L have to be the perpendicular bisector of PQ?

Comment: @Avi It doesn't *have* to be, strictly speaking, but it's a convenient choice. You want $R$ to move along a line such that the circle $PQR$ initially contains *all* $2 n + 1$ points, but contains *none* of them when $R$ moves far enough.

Comment: @Avi: As **dxiv** said, it doesn't; I just picked what I thought was the easiest approach to describe clearly.